# Python function can't see an imported module

Tags: python

Trying to read a csv into a list.

Code is as follows:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv','r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    mylist = list(reader)

print (mylist)

def gen_list():
    with open('file.csv','r') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        mylist = list(reader)
    print (mylist)

def main():
    gen_list()
    return 0
```

My output is:

```
[['one','two','three']]

Traceback():
....
line 11, in gen_list
reader = csv.reader(fin)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

I can prevent this error occurring by putting 'import csv' as the first line of the gen_list function.

why does the code not work when placed in a function?

Comment: Your indentation is off, right?

Additionally, do you happen to have a file named `csv.py` in the directory where you're running your code?

Comment: `def gen_list():` has indentation issues for line `reader = csv.reader(fin)`.

Comment: Is this the actual code (your indentation is off but I believe it's due to pasting)? Or do you assign something to variable `csv` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the indents. I do not have a file called csv.py in the directory, nor is the file itself named csv.py

Comment: What are the scripts called in that directory? You could have overriden something else

Comment: @Chris_Rands there's an assortment of python scripts. eg logExtractor.py drGenerator.py etc

Comment: I don't get why the code works in the first instance without issue but then throws a wobbly when its placed within a function

Comment: You could put a `print(csv)` before the line in question.

Comment: Where does your `main()` get called in the first place? Please show us your full code.

Comment: Is this ALL of the code? you're at the very least missing a call to main(). I strongly suspect you're doing `csv = <somestring>` at some point.

Comment: @Tordek you were right. Another function I was playing around with was:
def get_list(csv):

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using csv in another function by accident. Once I changed csv the issue went away

Function:

```
def get_list(csv):
    with open(csv,'rt') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            drList.append(gen_list(line))
        return (drList)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv','r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    mylist = list(reader)

print (mylist)

def gen_list():
    with open('file.csv','r') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)
        mylist = list(reader)
    print (mylist)

def main():
    gen_list()
    return 0
```

It seems that the indentation for `reader` within the `open` within `gen_list` is wrong

Comment: while the indentation is wrong, this doesn't explain the `AttributeError`

Comment: @llulai that is my code, I made an initial mistake in my question with the indentations